# what is the best software that can crop and trim video?

Tags: video, editing

it needs to work with mkv files

has to have a gui because the crops are different for each video

should be lightweight, I don't want to install premier just for this

Comment: You need to provide a little more information. Do you simply want to trim and crop? If so, windows life movie maker could be your thing. What sort of knowledge do you have in video editing? ffmpeg could be something for you if you are more skilled with a terminal.

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen `Do you simply want to trim and crop?` Yes as mentioned in the title. `windows life movie maker could be your thing.` movie maker has been deprecated and unavailable  in W10 for two years now. `ffmpeg could be something for you if you are more skilled with a terminal` as mentioned, a gui is required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good open source Video Editors?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors)

Comment: It's overkill to just trim and crop, but for general-purpose editing, Davinci Resolve from Blackmagic Design is excellent; the Studio version is a one-time $300 purchase (or included with many of their hardware products), but the baseline version is free-of-charge. I'm not adding this as an answer because I'm not sure product recommendation requests are allowed here -- most Stack Exchange sites don't permit them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is "the best" because that is a relative term. But a great option is VirtualDub2.

It is a GUI, preview the cropped result and you can directly stream the audio so it does not recompress for example.

You can also resample the rendered video because cropping changes the dimensions of it.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For anyone wondering, Adobe Media Encoder is great for trimming and cropping large amounts of video at once. Drag video files into the window, choose a preset, and hit the play button. You can create your own presets to reuse.

However .mkv is NOT SUPPORTED.

Comment: If it doesn't support .mkv, I don't see how it answers this question...